# Spring websocket Override DefaultUserDestinationResolver

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I want to override `DefaultUserDestinationResolver` so i can implement my custom queue user destination for example

`/user/queue/call` currently it is changed into `/queue/call-user{session-id}` , while in my case i want it to be changed into `/queue/call-{userid}`

The reason for this is that i want to be able to send a message to a user that is not subscribed yet and when he subscribe he can receive the message .

How can i ask spring to use my implementation of `UserDestinationResolver`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to implement `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport` for some of your `@Configuration` and override:

```
@Bean
public UserDestinationResolver userDestinationResolver() { 
...
}
```

for your purpose.

Comment: Worked perfectly , i extended WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport as it is class